# Inner Join and Cross Join yielding the same result

Tags: mysql, join

```
use classicmodels;

select Orders.OrderNumber,
       Customers.CustomerName,  Orders.Status, orders.shippeddate,
       Customers.Country
from Customers **cross join/inner join** Orders
on Customers.CustomerNumber = Orders.customerNumber
order by 1 asc
```

Hi all, I'm really confused as to why `inner join` in my query isn't really any different from the result of the `cross join`? I thought that `cross join` would result of a Cartesian product but both joins are giving me 326 rows. I've also seen somewhere that I shouldn't use non-unique data?

Comment: try removing the condition "Customers.CustomerNumber = Orders.customerNumber", is it the same result?

Comment: Yes, I removed that condition and tried both joins again. They both returned 39,772 rows.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) docs:

> In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents
>   (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not
>   equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used
>   otherwise.

Comment: Reading this made me cry a little... why would MySQL do something like this and disregard the ANSI standard :(